# Execute Crystal Report from C# Program

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have the following method in my C# program that generates a Crystal Report:

```
    public static ReportDocument CreateCrystalReport(String serverName, String databaseName, Boolean useIntegratedSecurity
        , String username, String password, String reportName, Dictionary<String, object> reportParams)
    {
        try
        {
            ReportDocument _report = new ReportDocument();
            _report.Load(reportName);

            // Define a new database connection
            ConnectionInfo _connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            _connectionInfo.ServerName = serverName.Trim(new char[] { '\\' });
            _connectionInfo.DatabaseName = databaseName;
            if (useIntegratedSecurity)
                _connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            else
            {
                _connectionInfo.UserID = username;
                _connectionInfo.Password = password;
            }

            // Replace the connection info associated with each table in the report with the updated connection information.
            foreach (Table _table in _report.Database.Tables)
            {
                TableLogOnInfo _logonInfo = _table.LogOnInfo;
                _logonInfo.ConnectionInfo = _connectionInfo;
                _table.ApplyLogOnInfo(_logonInfo);
            }

            // add parameters to report
            foreach (KeyValuePair<String, object> _param in reportParams)
            {
                _report.SetParameterValue(_param.Key, _param.Value);
            }

            return _report;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write(LogLevel.Error, "Error generating Crystal Report: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The report I am trying to run was built/tested in Crystal Reports, not directly in Visual Studio.  This is necessary as we have consultants that may add or modify Crystal Reports that this program will run.

In order to build/test this report I connected to my test database (Server A).  I then copied the report to another test machine (Server B) in which the C# program has a different SQL server database and credentials.  When I try to execute the report on Server B I get this error:

[image]

I then opened the report on Server B, hit F5 to run and modified the connection info in the report in order to get it to run.  The report now runs from both Crystal Reports and the C# program on Server B.

I then copy the report from Server B to Server A and when I try to run on Server A I get the same error as above.

It seems as though the connection info provided by the C# program is not being used when Crystal Report is connecting to SQL.  If I step through with debugging I can verify `_connectionInfo` in the code above is getting updated so I don't know why it isn't being used.

Is there some logon info or connection info I am missing when setting up the Crystal Report connection?  Is there something I need to do in the Crystal Report to tell it to use the connection info from the C# program?

Comment: does the reports maybe has any sub reports?

Comment: @mjwills The solution to this was to simply add `_report.Refresh()` after setting the connection info.  Thanks mjwills for the second link which prompted me to try this.